# VBA Macro to select different options from available Print window in IE

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a possibility to select the different option available from print window in IE in VBA

Answer (score 0):

It's a longshot but:

```
SendKeys ("^(p)")
```

Keep in mind that sendkeys has it's drawbacks. If the wrong window is active it will perform the action anyways.
Though CTRL+P is usually print, some software may differ and make this a serious issue

Comment: Thanks you for response..I am able to get to print window via "^(p)", but my request post sending "^(p)" it shows diffirent print options to select print er.From the available options I want to select bio-PDF

Comment: @SrinivasMantri Sorry can't help you then